# Throttle powershell jobs per computer

Tags: powershell, jobs, throttling

We have a script that is being called with different arguments for each computer. It can happen that the same script is called multiple times for the same computer, but with other arguments.

**Example code:**

```
$Jobs = @()
@(
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name='a';ComputerName='Pc1'}
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name='b';ComputerName='Pc1'}
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name='c';ComputerName='Pc1'}
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name='d';ComputerName='Pc2'}
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name='e';ComputerName='Pc2'}
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name='f';ComputerName='Pc3'}
).ForEach({
    $Jobs += Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
        Param ($Name)
        "$Env:COMPUTERNAME $Name"
    } -ComputerName $_.ComputerName -ArgumentList $_.Name -AsJob
})
```

We'd like to know how it is possible to limit the concurrently running jobs for one computer, to not overload the remote machine.

The CmeLet `Invoke-Command` exposes the parameter `-ThrottleLimit`, but this is only limiting the total of jobs launched at one time. Not the jobs running per computer.

We've tried playing with the [code suggested by Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/04/04/scaling-and-queuing-powershell-background-jobs/). but couldn't find a clean solution.

Comment: You can configure `winrm` to limit the number of concurrent connections.  Check out `winrm g winrm/config/winrs`.  You probably want to adjust `MaxShellsPerUser`

Comment: You can configure this in powershell with the following: `Set-Item -Path 'WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxShellsPerUser' -Value '3'`

Comment: It would be better to manage this manually with a counter in the code. Because some jobs are not resource intensive and others are as they require more CPU. Otherwise connections might get refused, and I'd rather have them queued up.

Comment: Without significantly overcomplicating the problem/answer, I don't think it's a simple fix.